# Can I determine page enter and leave in Angular2 (App also using ngrx/router)

Tags: animation, angular, rxjs, angular2-routing, ng-animate

I have an Angular2 app which uses the `ngrx/router`. Now when I was happy and using AngularJS I could easily animate page transitions using the css classes .`ng-enter, ng-enter, .ng-enter-active, .ng-leave, .ng-leave-active` and the angular-animate library. Now I wish to animate the page transitions of my Angular 2 app but I hear that the animate classes are now obsolete and animations should be conducted using a animations property in a `@Component` - however from the documentation this seems to deal more with state on specific elements rather than views... anyway, quick question, how can I determine page enter and page leave in Angualar2 and ngrx/router.

I know ngrx/router provides a LocationChange object/class but I am unsure if this will allow me to determine when we enter and leave a view / page.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Angular2 is indeed very component focused. Animating route changes was nicely described by Lukas Ruebbelke [1] and you will his example on a plunker [2] https://plnkr.co/edit/PcRpcGK2duGw0HdaGaF5?p=preview

Note how Lukas specified the details of the animation in a separate **routerTransition()** function imported into each route and added to the animations property of the relevant components (Home and About in his example):

```
  animations: [routerTransition()],
  host: {'[@routerTransition]': ''}
```

[1] http://ngmigrate.telerik.com/from-ng-animate-to-angular-2-animate

[2] https://plnkr.co/edit/PcRpcGK2duGw0HdaGaF5?p=preview